# Are libraries essential for building apps?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I recently started learning coding I actually didn’t know where to start after doing some researching I decided learning the javascript language as a first step . After finishing the courses on freecodecamp I didnt know what to do next I heard so many things to the point that I feel like I dont know anything . I would like someone to actually help me understand basics before languages, html css ... 
Here are my questions : 
Are libraries essential to build a website  or  create games ?
What ui and ux ? ( I heard that its for webpages designing though I also heard that css is also for web designing )
What’s a framework ? 
Does all languages have libraries ? 
Can you develop apps without libraries or frame work just using css html and javascript(example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, **opinion based**or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Are libraries essential to build a website or create games?

Yes. Any code you write will fundamentally become your library.

> What ui and ux?

UI is the **u**ser **i**nterface of any tool that requires input. UX is the **u**ser e**x**perience of a given interface. For example, an airplane pilot is given an interface to control the aircraft, and the controllers are meaningfully arranged to give the pilot the ability to fly safely. The result of the user experience is determined by the pilot's ability to accomplish a task.

> What’s a framework?

A framework is the foundation for deploying multiple functionalities for specific tasks. For example, an airport specifically manages how passengers arrive and depart to a new location by air travel. Similarly, a boating dock specifically manages how passengers travel over water. Here is a list of a few web frameworks out there: [Github Frameworks](https://github.com/topics/framework)

> Do all languages have libraries?

Most languages include built-in libraries. For example, Javascript includes basic math functions.

> Can you develop apps without libraries or frame work just using css html and javascript(example)

Yes and no. HTML is a markup language, and CSS is used to style your information. Fundamentally, you can write a static web app with html, hide or reveal information with css, and link out to other pages. If you intend to write an app with functionality that manipulates the HTML or CSS, you will need a programming language such as Javascript.

Answer (score -3):

**Are libraries essential to build a website or create games?** In a way no, but they will make your life much easier if you use them properly.

**What is UI and UX?** User Experience and User Interface. The first one (UX) is in charge of researching the user and it's context to plan and design the basic structure and flow of any platform, app, etc... The later (UI), using the UX outcome, manages the final design, the look-n-feel of it, as well as all the interactions.

**What’s a framework?** A library of a coding lenguage. They are very useful when you are developing, helps cut time if you can settle for somewhat generic functions-styles. Personally, I still customize the looks as some of them they can look a bit too generic

**Does all languages have libraries?** Most of them, yeah. All web development languages I know do.

**Can you develop apps without libraries or frame work just using css html and javascript(example)?** Yes, but for these lenguages it sounds like a waste of time not to use them. The basics to start on those 3 would be Bootstrap, jQuery and their